# Show "Typing..." for web based chat application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have almost completed my chat application using `php` & `ajax` functions .

Now question is , how to show "Typing.." (text) when the opposite user triggers the `keyup()` function from text-area.

My working structure :-

chat.php

```
 <?php

  // unique.html is created for each individual chat , just name is stored in database.
   //For eg :- Two user_id's(5,4) combined together forming 54.html ..& so on

 echo '<div id="mychat_box">

  //old content of chat/messages are loaded from an unique.html file here ..
   //working fine
 </div>

 <textarea id="usermsg" ><textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submitbutton">';
 ?>
```

Ajax functions

```
 $('#submitbutton').click(function(){
      $('#usermsg').val();
   //Content is posted to post.php via ajax
   //working fine

  });

  function Loadlog() {

  // This function loads/refresh the contents
  //(renders content from unique.html) inside the div mychat_box
       via setInterval() , 10 seconds.
   }
```

post.php

```
 <?php


   //content is accepted from the ajax call & posted to the unique.html file . 
  //also some information is collected & stored to database.
   //Working fine

  ?>
```

Above process is working fine , last need is to to add "Typing.." text dynamically(ajax ?) when the opposite user triggers the `keyup() function` as asked earlier.

Can anyone explain how can it be achieved ? Or explain me the logic behind it with some pseudo-code/article/tutorial ?

Will post code in more detail if necessary.

Comment: search for Websocket! that's what you'll need.

Comment: I don't have a favorite site that I could suggest, also I'm not an expert in websocket, sorry. But this could be a starting point: http://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html

Comment: and, yes, it's not that easy to be done I'm afraid.

Comment: And btw: If you manged to make it work you can restructure your chat-app to use it and get rid of the `setInterval`! Then you'll get an immidiate (more or less) response, not only after 10 seconds.

Comment: yes  @Jeff , i know that  .. Thanks for your help pal . Do suggest any other way if found , to get this achived..

Comment: Again , absolutely right @Jeff ... right now just doing stuff at basic level , seems like its time to be advance ..

Comment: I don't think there's another way to achieve this. Eighter a `setInterval` - which I consider a nt good solution -, or websocket. I myself will have to implement this in a few weeks, so I'm curious if you make it work!

Comment: Yes, it's always cool to try something new, more sofisticated, and make it work somewhen! Good luck & happy coding!

Comment: Ya thanks , need to see how websocket works & implemented  :D .. see u later ..

Comment: for PHP, EventSource will be a LOT easier to get up and running on most servers, and gives you the capability you need...

Comment: @dandavis , just had a look on that too ... understood it easily , but how its possible to achieve what i need using the EventSource . The logic behind it would be difficult as said by Jeff .. , do you have an logic dandavis ?